# receive all SQS messages via NodeJS client

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, queue, amazon-sqs

I am confused about the behaviour of the SQS Client in Node. It seems not possible to loop through all messages of a queue having a single SQS instance in place. The code below returns zero messages when loaded within the loop.

```js
const sqs = new SQS();    
let messages = await sqs.receiveMessage({ QueueUrl: "...", MaxNumberOfMessages: 10 }).promise();
while (messages?.Messages?.length > 0) {
  messages.Messages.forEach((message) => { console.log(message.Body); });
  messages = await sqs.receiveMessage({ QueueUrl: "...", MaxNumberOfMessages: 10 }).promise();
}
```

Once I changed the code to use a new instance of SQS inside the loop each time, as listed below, it works fine.

```js
let messages = await new SQS().receiveMessage({ QueueUrl: "...", MaxNumberOfMessages: 10 }).promise();
while (messages?.Messages?.length > 0) {
  messages.Messages.forEach((message) => { console.log(message.Body); });
  messages = await new SQS().receiveMessage({ QueueUrl: "...", MaxNumberOfMessages: 10 }).promise();
}
```

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find any hint about that in the documentation.

Does someone have a clue what causes that behaviour?

EDIT: added `await` keyword into the lines where `.promise()` is used. Thx to Mark B

Comment: I don't see how either version of your code is working at all since you aren't resolving or awaiting the `promise`.

Comment: thanks @MarkB, I edited the question. My fault.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out that the reason of the described behaviour was the fifo-configuration of the Queue.

Removing the `fifo: true` configuration solved my issue.